# Кодировка в MySQL и HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, mariadb, innodb

Ку, всем. Прошу помочь разобраться с кодировкой. В общем ситуация следующая, на локале все работает отлично и правильно. Перенесли на виртуальный сервер, запустили, установили такую же кодировку что и на локале, все русские слова стали ????????????. Самое интересное, что когда я добавляю и редактирую базу через админку, то в админке (на выводе) русские слова становяться нормальными, но в базе становятся кваказяброй.

Вот информация о базе на локале:

[image: информация о базе на локальном сервере]

А вот информация уже на боевом сервере:

[image: информация о базе на боевом сервере]

А вот так выглядит информация в базе, та что написана на русском - выводится на сайте как ???? а кваказябры, выводятся правильно! но в базе как видите не правильные.

[image: база с не правильной кодировкой]

На самом сайте установлена следующая кодировка:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Прошу помочь мне разобраться что нужно сделать, чтобы везде всё было правильно. Спасибо! Буду рад любым советам.

Мое подключение к базе:

```
public static function get_db(): void
    {
        self::$db = new Medoo([
            'database_type' => 'mysql',
            'database_name' => 'arenda_db',
            'server' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '12345'
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед переносом базы данных с одного сервера на другой первым делом выполните команду:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

или при экспорте или импорте данных настройте подключение по умолчанию: `utf8mb4_general_ci`

Также выполните эту команду на своем сайте, сразу после подключения к базе данных.

Comment: Доброе утро, при импорте базу у меня доступно только utf-8 http://joxi.ru/E2pz7bJF70Kbxr выбрал его. Я думаю может тогда перекодировать все в utf8? Так же вопрос по поводу команды : 'SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci' - она заменить все значения или же это некий перекодировщик при получении и сохранении в базу данных?

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8` просто говорит SQL-серверу в какой кодировке клинет будет посылать и принимать данные из базы данных. И таки нет (отставить перекодировку), utf8mb4 более полная по сравнению с utf8 (ака utf8mb3).

Comment: NoSkill сорри я совсем видимо нуб, я в тело вопроса скину свое подключение к базе, подскажите как мне правильно его дополнить что бы вписать эту команду, в документации я не нашол похожего.

Comment: Это просто запрос к базе данных... В точности как делаете "SELECT ...". Просто выполните запрос `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci`, как вы выполняете `SELECT ...`, `UPDATE ...`, `DELETE ...`

Comment: Да, сейчас я кажется нашел )делаю)

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! у меня немного по другому, так как я использую Medoo но вроде сработало )